# Consume .NET web service in Codename One by requesting parameters

Tags: codenameone, ksoap2

How to consume webservice dataset values in codename one?

My webservice returns results by passing three paramenters?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the webservice wizard as discussed in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/) and [in this video](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-remote-webservices-perform-operations-on-the-server.html). It essentially masks the webservice behind a proxy where you can write the webservice code in the server.